# Does Quasi Separation matter in R binomial GLM?

Tags: r, glm, logistic-regression, mle

I am learning how the quasi-separation affects R binomial GLM. And I start to think that it does not matter in *some circumstance*.

In my understanding, we say that the data has quasi separation when
some linear combination of factor levels can completely identify failure/non-failure.

So I created an artificial dataset with a quasi separation in R as:

```
fail <- c(100,100,100,100)
nofail <- c(100,100,0,100)
x1 <- c(1,0,1,0)
x2 <- c(0,0,1,1)
data <- data.frame(fail,nofail,x1,x2)
rownames(data) <- paste("obs",1:4)
```

Then when x1=1 and x2=1 (obs 3) the data always doesn't fail.
In this data, my covariate matrix has three columns: intercept, x1 and x2.

In my understanding, quasi-separation results in estimate of infinite value. So glm fit should fail. However, the following glm fit does NOT fail:

```
summary(glm(cbind(fail,nofail)~x1+x2,data=data,family=binomial))
```

The result is:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -0.4342     0.1318  -3.294 0.000986 ***
x1            0.8684     0.1660   5.231 1.69e-07 ***
x2            0.8684     0.1660   5.231 1.69e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Std. Error seems very reasonable even with the quasi separation.
Could anyone tell me why the quasi separation is NOT affecting the glm fit result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have constructed an interesting example but you are not testing a model that actually examines the situation that you are describing as quasi-separation. When you say: "when x1=1 and x2=1 (obs 3) the data always fails.", you are implying the need for an interaction term in the model. Notice that this produces a "more interesting" result:

```
> summary(glm(cbind(fail,nofail)~x1*x2,data=data,family=binomial))

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(fail, nofail) ~ x1 * x2, family = binomial, 
    data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.367e-17  1.414e-01   0.000        1
x1           2.675e-17  2.000e-01   0.000        1
x2           2.965e-17  2.000e-01   0.000        1
x1:x2        2.731e+01  5.169e+04   0.001        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1.2429e+02  on 3  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.7538e-10  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 25.257

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 22
```

One generally needs to be very suspect of beta coefficients of 2.731e+01: The implicit odds ratio i:

```
 > exp(2.731e+01)
[1] 725407933166
```

In this working environment there really is no material difference between Inf and 725,407,933,166.

Comment: yes, and note the Wald standard error of that term (`5.2e4`) (this is the *Hauck-Donner effect*).  If you wanted you could illustrate fixing the problem with `brglm::brglm()`, `logistf::logistf()`, `rms::lrm()` (with `penalty` parameter set), `arm::bayesglm()`,  ...

Comment: @BenBolker Should I post a question that asks for a learned-answer that helps me (and any other student of statistics) remember the difference between H-D and Q-S? They both are associated with mathematically ridiculous parameter estimates, but is it as simple as : QS associated with high `coef()`'s ...  HD with inflated `sem()`'s?

Comment: May I ask how exactly and practically I can check if data contains quasi separation? Is it sufficient to check whether I cab find some scalar s and a column vector x such that x[i] >= s then Y_i = 0 and  x[i] <= s then Y_i = 1 for all i = 1, ... , n (=sample size)? (In my setting, I only have binary covariate).

Comment: I *think* but am not sure that H-D refers to the failure of the Wald approximation in cases of "extreme" (but not necessarily completely quasi-separated?) parameter values in a binomial GLM.  You could ask (but CrossValidated would be a better venue than SO, I think)

Comment: That makes sense. In the example above none of the Wald tests are even close to being significant, despite a perfect model fit.